# BigQuery Query working with multiple "likes" but not working with "in"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-like, sql-in

I would like to isolate some emails with specific titles. I can use multiple "like"s connected with an ORs in the where clause. This gives me a number of results. However, if I try to do a ____ in ('____', '____', etc), the code suddenly returns nothing.

This does not work.

```
select DATE_TRUNC(DATE(send_time,"America/Los_Angeles"), week(monday)) as week,
status, 
settings_title,
sum(emails_sent) as emails_sent,
sum(report_summary_opens) as report_summary_opens, 
sum(report_summary_unique_opens) as report_summary_unique_opens, 
sum(report_summary_subscriber_clicks) as report_summary_subscriber_clicks
from mailchimp.campaigns_view
where status = 'sent' 
and settings_title in ('%_LL_%', '%_IC_%', '%_AC_%', '%_CC_%', '%_PC_%')
group by 1,2,3
order by 1 desc
```

However, this works.

```
select DATE_TRUNC(DATE(send_time,"America/Los_Angeles"), week(monday)) as week,
status, 
settings_title,
sum(emails_sent) as emails_sent,
sum(report_summary_opens) as report_summary_opens, 
sum(report_summary_unique_opens) as report_summary_unique_opens, 
sum(report_summary_subscriber_clicks) as report_summary_subscriber_clicks
from mailchimp.campaigns_view
where status = 'sent' 
and (settings_title like '%_LL_%'
or settings_title like '%_IC_%'
or settings_title like '%_AC_%'
or settings_title like '%_CC_%'
or settings_title like '%_PC_%')
group by 1,2,3
order by 1 desc
```

I have already tried to include a subquery in my "from" that eliminates all null settings_title. Any ideas why this is not working? Am I missing some small syntax error?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `%` symbol will only work with `LIKE`. For `IN` it's only equality. Try `REGEXP_CONTAINS` too.

As in:

```
SELECT REGEXP_CONTAINS("abcdefg", '(xxx|zzz|yyy|cd)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Felipe, very usefull!!!. In my case I used REGEXP_CONTAINS for matching with a multiple patterns added to a table. The select with the column "pattern_str" located in the second position is able to search and find correctly for every portion of the parttern:
WITH CTE_PatternCovid as (
Select STRING_AGG(Pattern,'|') as strPattern from `xxxxxxxxx.TEMP.Temp_patternsearch_covid` 
)
--this convert the multiple patterns into a single line:
--.*MASK.*FFP.*|.*MASK.*KN.*|.*TEST.*ANTIG.*|.*MASK.*QUI.*|.*SP.*H.DRO.*AL.*
--then use in this way:
Select ProductName FROM `xxxxxxxxx.TEMP.Table_ProductsName_covid` 
where
regexp_contains (upper(ProductName),(SELECT strPattern FROM CTE_PatternCovid ))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).